# Return link type property from org-follow-link-hook

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I would like org-mode to automatically narrow to subtree, when I follow an internal link. So, following [this thread](http://emacs-orgmode-gnu.git.net/2010-08/msg00281.html) I added this code to my init.el file:

```
(add-hook 'org-follow-link-hook (lambda () (org-narrow-to-subtree)))
```

This works great. But... it also narrows to the current subtree when I follow an external link (like a URL of a web page).

Is there some way to return the link type property (internal v. external) so that I can limit this behavior?

Something like this...

```
Org-follow-link hook
    If link type==internal
        Narrow
    End if
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the function and check whether you're in a different
location before narrowing.

```
(defun my-org-open-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((starting-loc (point)))
    (call-interactively #'org-open-at-point)
    (when (not (equal starting-loc (point)))
      (org-narrow-to-subtree))))

(define-key org-mode-map [remap org-open-at-point] 'my-org-open-at-point)
```

This works for internal links, but I thought it'd fail for links to
other files within Emacs (which could be fixed using markers). This
doesn't happen though because the current buffer stays the same.

```
(defun test-org-open-at-point-which-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (message "before call: %s" (current-buffer))
  (call-interactively #'org-open-at-point)
  (message "after call: %s" (current-buffer)))
```

I haven't looked at the source of `org-open-at-point` to figure out why
that is.

---

By the way, to get the link type, you can use

```
(org-element-property :type (org-element-context))
```

when the point is on a link.

Comment: Kyle, thanks for posting this. I am not able to get your first code block to work... does this work on your machine?

Comment: Yes, just tested it again on an internal link, on link to another file
in Emacs, and on a url. It seems to have the desired behavior (narrow to
the destination subtree for internal links).

I'm using the developmental version of Org (currently
release_8.3beta-580-g787733). When I tested it on the built-in version
of Org (8.2.10) for Emacs 24.4, it also works.

What is it doing on your end? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I'm using 24.3, on a Mac. Links get followed normally but without any narrowing (internal or otherwise)...